# Glide.js not responding

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, slider, glidejs

Hi i am currently building a cross platform app in cordova and have taken on the task of using Glide.js for an image slider i have followed its documentation word to word but am unable to understand why it is not working. For some reason it displays each image ontop of each other.

```
<div id="Glide" class="glide">
    <div class="glide__wrapper">
        <ul class="glide__track">
            <li class="glide__slide"><img src="images/Entrance_a.jpg" /></li>
            <li class="glide__slide"><img src="images/LDSAL_58.1.jpg" /></li>
            <li class="glide__slide"><img src="images/Entrance_b.jpg" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

and i have linked these scripts:

```
<link href="Glide.js-master/Glide.js-master/dist/css/glide.core.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="Glide.js-master/Glide.js-master/dist/css/glide.theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.5/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="Glide.js-master/Glide.js-master/dist/glide.js"></script>
```

Comment: Try: `new Glide('.glide').mount();`

Answer (score 0):

Are u sure css paths are correct? I think they should be like this:

```
<link href="Glide.js-master/dist/css/glide.core.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="Glide.js-master/dist/css/glide.theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: yes i am sure the css paths are correct as i have extracted the file inside a Glide.js-master folder and the extraction create a folder within my folder for itself. Could it be something wrong with the way the javascript files are loaded as with JQM since it is a single page structure after the home page it only loads the body of the next page each time?